# Filtering two arrays with a common id

Tags: mule, transform, dataweave, mule4

I have two payload from request. First payload I have the key number1 with value 12345 and I need find in payload2 the key id with the same value 12345

```
var payload1 = [{

"name": "kate",
"number1": 12345
}
]

var payload2 = [
{
"nameD": "kate P ",
"id": 12345,
"addres": Boston
},
{
"nameD": "John P ",
"id": 0986,
"address" : "New Jork"
}
]
```

```
payload2 filter ($.id == payload1."number1")
    map {
    id: $.id,
    nameD: $.nameD
}
```

But it's doesn't work. How I can't do it dynamically? Someone could help me ?
Thank you

Comment: payload1 is an Array. You should know how to access a particular property from array. try `payload[0].number1`

Comment: @HarshankBansal Hi, yes it's a array but in first payload1 I have only one key number1  but I would like have after transform and comparing value this:  [
{
"nameD": "kate P ",
"id": 12345} ]

Comment: What i meant is, in the filter condition you should be using `payload[0].number1` for comparison with `$.id`. It does not matter if it has one element or more. You have to access it with using an index if you want a single value as output

Answer (score 2):

Rather than filtering it looks like what you really want is to join the arrays by id==number1.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var payload1 = [{
        "name": "kate",
        "number1": 12345
    }
]

var payload2 = [
    {
        "nameD": "kate P ",
        "id": 12345,
        "addres": "Boston"
    },
    {
        "nameD": "John P ",
        "id": 986,
        "address" : "New Jork"
    }
]
---
leftJoin(payload1, payload2, (p1) -> p1.number1, (p2) -> p2.id)
    map {
            nameD: $.r.nameD,
            id: $.r.id
        }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "nameD": "kate P ",
    "id": 12345
  }
]
```

Comment: Please accept the answer to signal to others that it is helpful.